# how to set default language in google translator?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using this code for translation its working fine but I want to set Swedish lang as the default so that the page is automatically translated into swedish

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        autoDisplay: true,
        includedLanguages: 'sv,en',
    }, 'google_translate_element');
    setTimeout(() => {
        changeLangToSV();
    }, 2000);
}
function changeLangToSV(){
    let ele = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
        ele.selectedIndex = 1;
        ele.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// function googleTranslateElementInit() {
//   new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
// }

function setCookie(key, value, expiry) {
  var expires = new Date();
  expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    setCookie('googtrans', '/en/hi',1);
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
       pageLanguage: 'en'
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution.
You just have to remove the layout line.